# Minutiae feature extraction algorithm

Tags: matlab, fingerprint

In minutiae feature extraction algorithm for fingerprint, if i have extracted 90 points for example, 50 points end points and 40 for bifurcation points. I want to know if all the 90 points are considered as one ridge?! how can i know the points that are in the same ridge?!